# Meteor accounts set password throws server error

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I use "sendResetPasswordEmail" to send reset password email to newly created user. Email goes well and the link work as expected bringing the user who got the email to reset password route. After setting passwords and submitting the form I get the following error in server(see below screenshot) and an "Internal error" message in client.

[image]

The user is actually created and has a token in password property but the password is not set.
I am having really bad time debugging it because I can not find the source. What am I doing wrong here? Is "sendResetPasswordEmail" used only when reseting existing user?

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a newly-created user to set password, use `Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail`.

Read [this docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-sendEnrollmentEmail) for information about how to use `Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail`.

Comment: I was thinking about that but did not try it. I will give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: I voted for your help, but that did not fix it. After spending a lot of time I made a meteor update and the issue was not reproduced anymore.

Comment: Glad that you're not facing the issue anymore.